# After Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade, two different lock screens

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, login, password, suspend

I've done a lot of searching around for a solution but only found results that were only similar to my problem and not quite exactly the same.

My problem is that ever since I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04, I have two login prompts--the old one from 12.04 and then the new one from 14.04.

If I disable the need for a password entirely, then the old prompt still shows up.

What I want to happen is to get rid of the old 12.04 password prompt entirely and only login with the newer 14.04 prompt.

Whenever I wake my laptop from being suspended, I get these two different prompts. I only want to use the second one after opening my laptop.

Also, many times after a successful login my top and side bars will be weird colors and none of the icons will appear. Only after I guess where one of my sidebar programs is and click on it, the colors return to normal.

How can I get to a normal state of affairs where I can simply just login with the left-aligned password screen after opening my laptop and not get weird discoloration?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling lightgdm sudo apt-get reinstall lightgdm.
Otherwise it might be worth reinstalling the system, if you make a bootable usb you can upgrade the system without deleting your files (read carefully when it asks you how to install ubuntu on your hard disk!). Make sure to use the latest version of ubuntu.